# how do i integrate paynow zimbabwe api with a localhost system?

Tags: php

Can you please help me to integrate paynow zimbabwe gateway with my localhost system.I have tried to follow their documentation https://developers.paynow.co.zw/docs/quickstart.html but I failed. I want the user to be redirected to the paynow page to pay penalties.Also the result or status must be obtained in order to update the system database. Is it possible to link a localhost system to the paynow api or my system have to be live?. Thank you in advance

```
<?php
        include "./includes/tables_header.php";
        include "./includes/db.php";
        
        require_once "./paynow/autoloader.php";
        use Paynow\Payments\Paynow;
        if(isset($_POST['Paynow']))
           {
        
        class Payow{
        public function paynows($amount)
        {
        $siteurl="http://localhost/online_offenceTracking_system/payment1.php?";//substitute with your own return url   
        define('ps_error', 'Error');
        define('ps_ok','Ok');
        define('ps_created_but_not_paid','created but not paid');
        define('ps_cancelled','cancelled');
        define('ps_failed','failed');
        define('ps_paid','paid');
        define('ps_awaiting_delivery','awaiting delivery');
        define('ps_delivered','delivered');
        define('ps_awaiting_redirect','awaiting redirect');
        define('site_url', $siteurl);
        
        $int_key="###########";//get from paynow.co.zw
        $int_id=#######;//get from paynow.co.zw, it should be an intenger 
        $paymentid="testID1234hs";
        $url="https://www.paynow.co.zw/interface/initiatetransaction/?";
        $reference=sha1(Paynow\Payments\Paynow::$app->user->identity->email);
        $amount=6.25;
        $returnurl="http://localhost/online_offenceTracking_system/payment1.php?r=credit/index"; //substitute with your own return urls
        $resulturl="http://localhost/online_offenceTracking_system/payment1.php?r=credit/index"; //substitute with your own return urls
        $authemail="acmwamuka@gmail.com";//This is the buyer's email address
        $additionalinfo="Paying for canteen meals.";
        $concat=$int_key.$int_id.$paymentid.$url.$reference.$returnurl.$resulturl.$authemail.$additionalinfo;
        $concat=$concat.$int_key;
        $values = array('resulturl' => $resulturl,
                    'returnurl' =>  $returnurl,
                    'reference' =>  $reference,
                    'amount' =>  $amount,           
                    'id' =>  $int_id,
                    'additionalinfo' =>  $additionalinfo,
                    'authemail' =>  $authemail,
                    'authphone' =>  "07777777777",
                    'status' =>  'Message'); //just a simple message
                    
        $fields_string = $this->CreateMsg($values,$int_key);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false); //need fixing
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if($result)
            {
                $msg = $this->ParseMsg($result);        
                if ($msg["status"] == ps_error){
                    header("Location: $checkout_url");          
                    exit;
                }
                else if ($msg["status"] == "Ok"){
                    $validateHash = $this->CreateHash($msg, $int_key);
                    if($validateHash != $msg["hash"]){
                        $error =  "Paynow reply hashes do not match : " . $validateHash . " - " . $msg["hash"];
                        echo $error;
                    }
                    else
                    {               
                        $theProcessUrl = $msg["browserurl"];
                    //echo $theProcessUrl; 
                    //header("Location: ".$theProcessUrl);
                        Paynow\Payments\Paynow::$app->response->redirect($theProcessUrl);
                        $orders_array = array();                
                    }
                }
                else {                      
                    //unknown status or one you dont want to handle locally
                    $error =  "Invalid status from Paynow, cannot continue.";
                }
        
            }
            else
            {
               $error = curl_error($ch);
               echo $error;
            }
            //print_r($result);
            //close connection
            curl_close($ch);
        
        }
        public function ParseMsg($msg) {
            $parts = explode("&",$msg);
            $result = array();
            foreach($parts as $i => $value) {
                $bits = explode("=", $value, 2);
                $result[$bits[0]] = urldecode($bits[1]);
            }
        
            return $result;
        }
        
        function CreateMsg($values, $MerchantKey){
            $fields = array();
            foreach($values as $key=>$value) {
               $fields[$key] = urlencode($value);
            }
        
            $fields["hash"] = urlencode($this->CreateHash($values, $MerchantKey));
        
            $fields_string = $this->UrlIfy($fields);
            return $fields_string;
        }
        
        public function UrlIfy($fields) {
            $delim = "";
            $fields_string = "";
            foreach($fields as $key=>$value) {
                $fields_string .= $delim . $key . '=' . $value;
                $delim = "&";
            }
        
            return $fields_string;
        }
        
        
         public function CreateHash($values, $MerchantKey){
            $string = "";
            foreach($values as $key=>$value) {
                if( strtoupper($key) != "HASH" ){
                    $string .= $value;
                }
            }
            $string .= $MerchantKey;
            
            $hash = hash("sha512", $string);
            return strtoupper($hash);
        }
            
        
        
        }}
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a free service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) to expose your localhost environment to the world wide web. Just make sure your `returnurl` and `resulturl` are using your ngrok address so that Paynow can callback your application.